# ReportViewer in Winform doesn't show correctly the page designed in RDLC Report - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, printing, rdlc, reportviewer

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 with VB.NET

I've prepared a rdlc report, with rectangles and textboxes (no tables, cause I don't need to show any dataset, but only a list of data resulting by an elaboration).

I simply need to print this report on a common A4 paper, so I've added a reportviewer correctly connetted with my rdlc report.

In the rdlc report design screen I correclty see my report, with rulers on the left and on the top, that correctly indicate the A4 measures: 21cm W x 29,7 H.

Also my rdlc report InteractiveSize and PageSize are set on 21cm x 29,7cm , with 1cm; 1cm; 1cm; 1cm in margins.

With this situation, I start the program, make the elaboration and view my report in reportviewer after the elaboration. In its layout view, my rdlc report is shown like "pressed" and miniaturized on the left, with the header of the rdlc report that is repeated along 3 pages. The first page contains both header and all textboxes with solid borders, small and pressed on the left of the reportviewer view, while page 2 and 3 have only the header, with the rest blank.

If I print this reportviewer view, I get on paper exactly what I see in the reportviewer layout view, while if I export it in a pdf, I get 3 pages, but this time they are not smaller and pressed on the left of the screen, instead they correclty fit my rdlc original settings, even if the header is repeated along 3 pages again (but not "smallerized" this time).

I'm forced to ask this question cause after a long search I haven't found any solution, despite the big amount of topics I've read where users ask similar problems with this reportviewer.

Really hope in some suggestion.

Comment: Are you sure that there are no overlapping controls? It is my experience that in rendering to targets other than reports view, the slightest overlap may mess things up.

Comment: first of all thank you for interest in my problem, I was about to losing all hopes. yes, this could be, in the rdlc report I have manually created a grid of textboxes very close one to the next, for reply a table layout without using a table object (cause, as I said, I don't need datasets here and with a table I would be forced to refer the table to one). the fact is that all textboxes should have 1pixel of border/margin, in some parts of the rdlc these margins could be overlapped. just to be sure, you mean overlap in rdlc view, not something about report viewer, right?

Comment: indeed, i mean no overlapping rectangles in design view.

Answer (score 0):

You can decrease the size of your RDLC report page, it will not add additional page in PDF and would correctly fit with your default settings.

Comment: yes, I've solved the additional pages problem, but in the reportviewer-layoutview I've always my view "smallerized" and on the left of the virtual A4. By the way, also in the pdf the view of the page in Acrobat Reader is a bit forced on the left, didn't pay attention at this before, cause I was searching about solutions for reportviewer view. For sure this has much less evidence than in the reportviewer, I could stay with this, but seems absurd not to get a solution about this problem.

Comment: I think you can accomplish this by changing the padding of your reportviewer, isn't it.

Comment: yes, I've set all those margins to 0, and for this you could say: "ahh, so is for this that you see the layoutview on the left!" => and you would be right, but... if I expand my rdlc contents on the right (I mean, create a textbox along all the width of the rdlc which has dimensions set to A4 standard, and rulers that indicate the 21cm size, and I write until the end of this textbox), at a certain point in the reportviewer I see my content go in a newline, restarted from the extreme left margin without have fit the complete space available on the A4 virtual paper on the right in the prev row.